# PHP session corrupt

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, symfony1, session

Using symfony framework 1.4 I have created a website. I'm using sfguard for authentication.

Now, this is working great on WAMP (windows). I can login to several accounts on different browsers and use the website.

I have ubuntu server 9.10 running apache (everything up to date and default configuration). On my server, when I login to the website in one browser it works great. When I on my other computer login with another user account on the public website, the login is successful. But when I refresh/go to another page the first user is shown as logged in instead!

Also, when I press logout, It's not showing that I'm logged out after page load. When I press f5 again I'm logged out.

As mentioned, all this works as expected on my local installation. I'm thinking there something wrong with my PHP session configuration on my ubuntu server, but I've never touched it..

Please help me. This is a school project and I'm presenting it today :(

Comment: Have you made sure you've done a symfony clear-cache on the production box?
This seems to solve many stange symfony issues like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unlikely to be the session handler (certainly not the problem if you are using the default handler). Top of my list of things to check is whether you are sending out the right caching information in the authenticated pages (i.e. either no-cache or Varies: cookie).

C.